# PHP Factory Pattern will create an Object with its Dependencies

Tags: php, ebay-api

I am using this library [ebay-sdk-php](https://github.com/davidtsadler/ebay-sdk-php) I like to have a Factory that will create a Request object with its dependencies(require_once). The Request object is a singleton here. And I am not getting the Request object that is GetSellerEventsRequestType and need to use all require_once files.

```
<?php
//NAMESPACE 
use \DTS\eBaySDK\Constants;
use \DTS\eBaySDK\Trading\Services;
use \DTS\eBaySDK\Trading\Types;
use \DTS\eBaySDK\Trading\Enums;

final class Factory{
    public static function Instantiate(){
        static $Request=null;
        if($Request===null){
            $Request=new Types\GetSellerEventsRequestType();
        }
        return $Request;
    }
    private function __construct(){
        //REQUIRED FILES INCLUSION
        require_once(__DIR__.'/../../../../vendor/autoload.php');
        require_once(__DIR__.'/../../../../../Config/Config.php');
        require_once(__DIR__.'/../../../../../Helper/Helper.php');
    }
}
$Request=Factory::Instantiate();
var_dump($Request);
```

Comment: And your question is...?

Comment: `Factory::Instantiate` do not call `__construct`.

Comment: yes, its not calling constructor in this code.